# How can I access the $location service without using it in the .controller()?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.  I am trying to change the location of the URL only when a jquery ajax response is successful. But the issue is the only way I know how to use the `$location` service is through the controller.

I only want to run the `$location.path('/');` when an ajax response is complete.

This is what I have for now..

```
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$location){

    $location.path('/basemenu');

    })
```

But I can't run it only on success because it will give me an error, and I can't run on the page load either.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: where is your ajax calling? There's no problem doing jquery calls inside angular controller. But you may want to use angular's $http server instead.

Comment: please post your code for `$.ajax` call

Answer (score 0):

$location service is a wrapper built around window.location.
in browser's context window object is exposed to all js snippet ( controller,service,factory etc..)
use

```
window.location.pathname = '<new path>';
```